# how to make a new 0 and 1 column?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I wanna make a new columns with 0 and 1:

if `col1` is zero and `col2` is positive set new column to 1.
if 'col1`is zero and`col2`is negative set new column to 0. if`col1`is 1 and`col2 `is positive set new column to 0. if 'col1` is 1 and `col2` is negative set new column to 1.

```
col1   col2
0       2
0       -4
1       -2
1       5
1       9

new_colum
1
0
1 
0
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if col2 is positive and get the absolute difference with col1 (booleans behave like 0/1):

```
df['new_column'] = df['col1'].sub(df['col2'].gt(0)).abs()
```

Or, compare the two outputs, you want them to be different:

```
df['new_column'] = df['col1'].ne(df['col2'].gt(0)).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  new_column
0     0     2           1
1     0    -4           0
2     1    -2           1
3     1     5           0
4     1     9           0
```